# linux mint periodically freezing after closing lid

Tags: x11, freeze

After closing the lid of my laptop I suffer a periodic freezing system (~0.5 seconds). The symptoms are:

- mouse pointer stops
- keyboard input stops (=delayed)
- video freezes
- ms teams meetings stuck
- (rarely sometimes the "internet" is not working)

My System:

- Linux Mint Dell 13 9315 with Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon
- usb-c-hub with 3 HDMI, USB-C, USB3.x, Card- and Ethernet slots
- 2 external displays connected via an usb-c hub

I can see in the log file of XOrg, that every 30 seconds new entries are produced.

from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```bash
[ 22306.736] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 22306.737] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 22306.737] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 22306.737] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 22306.737] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 41146
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync +vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
[ 22337.678] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
```

- I can trigger the same outputs if i call `xrandr --listproviders`.
- There are no conf files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

I am not quite sure where the problem is located but i seems that closing the lid triggers a periodic scan for displays.

`inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1: 1920x1200~60Hz
    2: 1920x1200~60Hz 3: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
```

`free -h`

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       8,1Gi       1,8Gi       2,1Gi       5,4Gi       4,6Gi
Swap:          2,0Gi        92Mi       1,9Gi
```

i also add ppa from oem-solutions to add camera support:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output on `inxi -G` so we can see your graphics card and what driver you are using. Does this only happen when running Teams?

Comment: no, always every 30 seconds. When i am watching a youtube video or scrolling a page in a browser...

Comment: Please edit your question and post `free` output. This looks like a memory exhaustion issue. This could also be caused by dying storage or a bad video card/driver.

Comment: do you have suggestions for maybe "the right" driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem started immediately after i closed the lid.
You can solve this temporarily with

```bash
killall csd-power
```

for further investigation details run the following command and close the lid again:

```bash
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-power --verbose
```

as the name suggest the problem belongs to the power setting. At the very end the problem was solved by simply activating:

`Perfom lid-closed action with external monitors attached` in the Power Management setting

[image]